# Cloudkit error when querying public database from simulator

Tags: ios8, cloudkit, xcode6.1

I'm working on an app where I recently decided to go with CloudKit and am now at the point where I need to implement the backend functionality. In a nutshell, this app will use a collectionview to display images retrieved from a CK database. Up until now, I just dumped some images in a folder on my desktop and retrieved/parsed the images from there to render the collectionview. I then used the CK dashboard to create some records and wrote an initialization method to try and retrieve them. I was getting various CKErrors, such as network failure, error completion without receiving a response from the server, could not send a valid signature, etc. I immediately assumed the issue was with my code since it was my first attempt with CloudKit. However, I ran the latest code on my device before posting on SO and it worked! I got a successful response with the number of records in the results array that I was expecting.

So now I know longer need help with fetching CKRecords like I initially thought. But how do I resolve this issue with the simulator? I saw some other post about making sure you're signed into iCloud on the simulator. I believe I am, but do not know how to check to be sure. Also, I'm running Yosemite and Xcode 6.1.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use your Apple ID on iCloud on the iPhone Simulator, make sure you turn off Two-way authentication. It should then work on the simulator.

Comment: This works for me when hitting the CloudKit Development environment, but not the Production one, I'm still getting `<CKError 0x79f38700: "Internal Error" (1/1000); "Received a didCompleteWithError without receiving a response from the server">`

Comment: @Marcus Same issue in iOS 9 - I suppose it just won't work from the simulator.

Answer (score 16):

on the simulator go to the settings app. You can do that with menu hardware, home and then open the settings app, select iCloud and make sure that you are logged in.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think of that. I did go into the settings on the simulator and signed in. After agreeing to the terms, it gave an error saying this device is not supported. I clicked on learn more and signed into icloud in safari via the simulator. It looks like it wants me to confirm the identity like I recently did on my actual phone, but the screen won't let me see the entire page. Pinching doesn't seem to work either. Did you encounter this as well?

Comment: Worked for me-- but I have a follow up question, would my users have to be signed into iCloud in order to access data in the "public" database?  Why does this fix the issue?

Comment: yes, when you want to connect to CloudKit the use has to be signed in into iCloud. CloudKit is build on top of iCloud. The authentication is handled using the iCloud credentials.

Comment: @AO: A comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321975/couldnt-send-a-valid-signature-error-when-using-cloudkit-without-icloud-accou explains that login is needed to access public databases in development, but won't be needed in production.