# “Couldn't send a valid signature” error when using CloudKit without iCloud account

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have submitted an iOS app that uses CloudKit to Apple. It's being rejected because it requires user to sign into iCloud for access. Apple's reasoning is that even without iCloud sign-in, the public database is still readable. So that part of the app should function.

I am trying to modify the app but I continue to get this error when I am not signed in.

```
<CKError 0x8141a360: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't send a valid signature">
```

I have searched the web and the solution is always just to sign into iCloud. There is no Apple documentation regarding this error either. Does anyone know how to resolve this without signing into an iCloud account? Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, I found the reason and I want to leave it here so if others have the same problem they will know why. Apparently I didn't read this when I started to develop the app a year ago. In Apple's CloudKit Quick Start Guide: "In development, when you run your app through Xcode on a simulator or a device, you need to enter iCloud credentials to read records in the public database. In production, the default permissions allow non-authenticated users to read records in the public database but do not allow them to write records." Now I need to somehow find a development device so I can test it. :(

Comment: to make this more useful to others it would be useful to post this as an answer and mark it as correct - you can do that for your own questions.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error but a slightly different cause, so for this problem another thing to check (other than that @Cakelly posted themselves as a comment):

This error can also occur if you try to access the Production database from the simulator, even if you are signed in to iCloud. Change back to the Development database to test on a simulator.

Comment: Also note that you have to delete the app and rerun it after changing that value, otherwise you'll continue to get that error.

Comment: Ahh, trying to get screenshots but all my data is in production database.  This does indeed complicate matters.  With no way to export and import the data between databases does this mean I have to reenter thousands of records?

Comment: @robwithhair Yeees, possibly. Or make a test build of your app that mocks up the screens to look like they have lots of real data behind them?